# Is it possible to see input data passed to kernel in gDEBugger?

Tags: debugging, opencl

I'm currently learning OpenCL and got some problems with my program ( running fine on GPU but not on CPU). So I wanted to try gDebugger. I'd like to know if it's possible to see the input data passed to the kernel in gDebugger and if so how can I see. I searched but couldn't get information. I hope you'll be able to help.

Take care.

Best regards,

Jacq

Answer (score 0):

You can see the input and output buffers in the Textures and Buffers viewer.

P.S: gDEBugger was replaced by CodeXL (http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/). You will enjoy this one...